# Balanceadores de carga, seguridad con jwt y otras cuestiones

Tags: angular, spring-boot, jwt

Quizás sea un post de opiniones, pero aún así, pediría que no lo cierren, aprovecho para decir que estoy en contra de esa norma, las opiniones de las personas son experiencias que ayudan u orientan a los menos experimentados.

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en el front con Angular4, y Java (Springboot). Dicha aplicación dispone de un Login:

El login envía el usuario/contraseña al servidor y el servidor responde con un true o false, el typescript de Angular comprueba eso y si es true, permite el acceso.

Ahora me piden desarrollar todo el tema de seguridad usando un JWT (nunca lo he hecho), hasta donde he leído el front envía las credenciales al servidor, éste las validará y enviará un token JWT al front y durante toda la aplicación se usará este token de validación, eso está muy bien a lo largo de la aplicación, **pero le veo lagunas** en la autenticación en el frontal.

```
El front envía Edu/1234 y el back responde con eyMeloInvento.algo=
```

1º
¿ Desde la parte del front, cómo voy a comprobar que la respuesta es la correcta ?
Front :

```
   this.service.Login(this.user.credentials).subscribe(data => {
            if(data.token === "eyMeloInvento.algo="){
              router.navigate["welcome"]
             }
    });
```

Esto es invalido, ya que no sabría que poner en la condición del if, porque no sé que token se va a generar...

2º Aunque solucionase el problema anterior ¿Cómo se evita que en las páginas webs se ponga un punto de ruptura en el if del front para la comprobación y darle el valor de true para permitir el acceso ?

Le veo estas lagunas en la autenticacion por token jwt...

Después durante la ejecución, se usará el jwt entre front y back para confirmar que es el usuario logueado en la aplicación, ¿¿ pero qué ocurre con los balanceadores ??, es decir, el micro servicio que se ha desplegado y atendió la solicitud del navegador del usuario "edu" generó un token, por motivos de carga, ahora la petición de la web de edu ya no es atendida por el mismo micro servicio que tenía su token, ¿ qué va a ocurrir ?

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te explico tus dudas:

> ¿Desde la parte del front, cómo voy a comprobar que la respuesta es la
>   correcta?

Esta parte es sencilla: haces una petición de login (con un usuario y contraseña, por ejemplo) y si el servidor la acepta, tendrás una respuesta `HTTP 200 OK` con un token válido. **No tienes que validar nada en frontend**, porque si la contraseña no fuera correcta, entonces no hubieses obtenido el token, seguramente backend hubiese respondido con un `HTTP 401 Unauthorized`.

> Aunque solucionase el problema anterior ¿Cómo se evita que en las
>   páginas webs se ponga un punto de ruptura en el if del front para la
>   comprobación y darle el valor de true para permitir el acceso?

Al igual que antes, realmente no es tu problema, ya que no se puede evitar que el usuario trastee con el Javascript en SU computadora. 
En este escenario, es el backend el que validará las peticiones: sin token, cualquier llamada debería responder de nuevo un `HTTP 401 Unauthorized`.
Por tanto la aplicación Angular será incapaz de obtener información, y seguramente se "romperá" (de nuevo, no es tu problema, el usuario no debería trastear con el código).

> ... el micro servicio que se ha desplegado y atendió la solicitud del
>   navegador del usuario "edu" generó un token y, por motivos de carga,
>   ahora la petición de la web de edu ya no es atendida por el mismo
>   micro servicio que tenía su token, ¿ qué va a ocurrir ?

De nuevo, no tiene que pasar nada, el token es validable por sí mismo. El servidor tomará el token, usará su clave para comprobar la firma y verá que es válido. No es necesario guardarlo en la base de datos.